# How to change Phabricator svn+ssh URIs?

Tags: svn, phabricator

I sync a project from SVN server to Phabricator.
svn+ssh works fine, but the uri shows "svn+ssh://IP/**source**/project".
How can I change it from **source** to **svn** ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr9uB.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [Phabricator source](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/a778151f28c16ef8feb01830be9216245f177366/src/applications/repository/storage/PhabricatorRepositoryURI.php#L417), there are three possibilities to set the URL for the given Phabricator repository, these all happen in the basic setting of the repository:
[image]

1) Setting only the name leads to these kind of URLs:

```
/diffusion/{$id}/{$clone_name}{$suffix}
```

2) Setting Call Sign (Which can only be uppercase) leads to these kind of URLs:

```
/diffusion/{$callsign}/{$clone_name}{$suffix}
```

3) Setting Short Name leads to these kind of URLs:

```
/source/{$short_name}{$suffix}
```

So to answer your question this is not possible without a change to the Phabricator source code.

Comment: Hi @Pouyan, thanks for your answer. There are many external links to /svn/.../... in my project. Do you have good suggestion to fix it without changing the settings or do less modification?